# Issue with ibm_db module installation on Linux OS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, db2

I am experiencing an issue while installing IBM_DB module on Linux SUSE. Here is the detailed explanation of the issue.

My NodeJS API is using IBM_DB module. In my Windows machine, I am able to install the drivers without issues. So it is working fine in my local machine.

Now I need to deploy my API on linux OS (Linux SUSE version), there I am able to install express, http all other modules except ibm_db. While installing the ibm_db drivers, it is giving below errors.

I have tried with different node versions 0.12.7, 4.2.5, and latest version 5.5, but getting same error with any version.

Can someone please help me how can I resolve this issue?
Can I use ibm_db module if someone has already downloaded it on different linux machine? Is there any location where I can download compressed file of ibm_db module?

```
10234 error argv "/home/praisons/node-v4.2.5-linux-x86/bin/node" "/home/praisons/node-v4.2.5-linux-x86/bin/npm" "install" "--save"
10235 error node v4.2.5
10236 error npm  v2.14.12
10237 error code ELIFECYCLE
10238 error ibm_db@0.0.15 install: `node installer/driverInstall.js`
10238 error Exit status 1
10239 error Failed at the ibm_db@0.0.15 install script 'node installer/driverInstall.js'.
10239 error This is most likely a problem with the ibm_db package,
10239 error not with npm itself.
10239 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10239 error     node installer/driverInstall.js
10239 error You can get their info via:
10239 error     npm owner ls ibm_db
10239 error There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Could you check for errors of driverInstall.js? https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/installer/driverInstall.js  It tries to download the needed drivers and install them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, "npm install ibm_db" is not supported on non-windows platform for node.js v4.x. Please use node.js v0.12.7 on linux. The latest released version of ibm_db is 0.0.17 not sure why it is still showing ibm_db@0.0.15 for you! It might be the root cause. Thanks.

Comment: ibm_db@0.0.19 works on all platforms with node.js V 0.10.x, v0.12.x, v4.x and v5.x . Thanks.